# jQuery AJAX call works in Firefox but not IE - valid response returned

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, internet-explorer

I am having a strange issue with an AJAX call where it is working in Firefox, but not in IE.  When I add an IE alert(), I see the returned content, but it does not want ot insert with the jQuery .html() command.  Here is my sample code:

```
$(document).on('click','.OpenForm',function(e) {    
    e.preventDefault();
    var FormControl = $(this).attr('id');       //ex: id=FormView_12 or FormEdit_12
        FormControl = FormControl.split('_');
    var FormControlType = FormControl[0];
    var FormID = FormControl[1];
    $.post("./includes/Getform.php", { "t" : "view" , FormID : FormID })  
     .done(function(data) {
      if (data.length>0){
        data = data.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
        //alert(data); ---THIS ALERTS THE RESPONSE IN IE8
        //console.log(data); --- THIS SHOWS RESPONSE IN FF
        $('.ProjectContentLoad').html(data).show();
      }
   })
   .fail( function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      error_handling(xhr.responseText);
   });
});
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the console.log()?

Comment: No luck, I was just alternating between an alert in IE and console.log in FF.  Should have mentioned in the initial post that I am using IE8.

Comment: * IE has issues with `console.log(...)` if the developer tools aren't open... it will silently crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your returned HTML is invalid. FF doesn't have problems with that, but IE8 sure does ;)  Maybe you forget to close a div?

The following post shows some guys having the exact same problem: [jQuery AJAX GET html data IE8 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792815/jquery-ajax-get-html-data-ie8-not-working/8957983#8957983)

Comment: Seems so simple but that was the problem - I had a </div> in the wrong place.  Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any error message on your JS console ? Can you show what data content is ?

I'm thinking about 2 things:

1) If you don't run development tools in IE8, console.log() is undefined. To solve it, put this code at the top of your page :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> if (!window.console) console = {log: function() {}}; </script>
```

source : ['console' is undefined error for Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326650/console-is-undefined-error-for-internet-explorer)

2) Maybe an AJAX cache issue with IE (I don't think because you are using post() ), try to put this code at the top of your page :

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

source: [How to prevent a jQuery Ajax request from caching in Internet Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303829/how-to-prevent-jquery-ajax-caching-in-internet-explorer)

Comment: breaking it up into two parts is a bad suggestion.

Comment: Oh, yes you're right, `.html( htmlString )` return a JQuery object. http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2, I edit my message.

Comment: Breaking it up into two parts didn't resolve the issue.  ALso added the cache:false command with no luck, checking to make sure the HTML is valid now...

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark, but IE isn't getting confused by the JS object you're sending is it?

```
{ "t" : "view" , FormID : FormID }
```

Is there any reason you're using a string as a key for "t"?

Comment: Why would it be confused? That is a valid object.